# Multiple Raspberry Pi 3 Server monitoring and job automation tools with GUI

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to have a centralized server monitoring and job automation tools with web GUI to manage 50+ raspberry Pi installed at various location within the same network (192.168.1.0/24).

1. Monitoring (online/offline is a must, show cpu/ram etc are better options)
2. Automate install new patches, reboot Pis, restart services, upload/download files etc. (puppet can do it)
3. Free and Opensource. (I have no budget to pay)

The Pi installed with Debian Jessie latest version.

Any recommendations?

Comment: It looks like Chef might be what you need for automation.  It is open source.  What is "offline" monitoring?

Comment: if one of the Pi goes offline, I will see it get "red" flag warning on the web gui. So I can to to check that Pi and make it online by reboot or whatever.

Comment: Puppet and nagios would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend taking a look at PiChef, a Pi implementation of the Chef configuration management system.  https://github.com/ranjib/PiChef

Answer (score 0):

You could use:
cayenne.mydevices.com
It's free for end users and has some pretty cool features.
Has RPI and Arduino integration.
Agent for RPI is giving a lot of informations about the system and you can also integrate sensors since it's fully integrated with sensor drivers.

Alternatives(you will need to code your side):

- Openhab
- Developer android things (cannot post the link since I don't have enough reputation). Android for RPI works just for RPI3.

Some other things to mention:

- Platform is gaining a lot o users
- A lot of cool features like: Alerts, cross .
- Community link is easy to find on the platform
- I am one of the developers