# What is os_config.json and where is it documented?

Tags: raspbian, boot, image

I'm using Raspbian Jessie Lite, and during startup there's a line:

```
Started LSB: Apply config from /boot/os_config.json.
```

What is os_config.json? Is there documentation for it somewhere? What is it used for?

I'm trying to customize an image and that sounds like something I should look at, either to avoid building something myself that's already done or give me an idea of and/or do something I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os_config.json` is used by [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md), and the message you are seeing comes from `/etc/init.d/apply_noobs_os_config`.  This is left default enabled but I would presume it disables itself after the first run; i.e., somewhat like `raspi-config` it is run as a once only service.  I'd also presume on a non-NOOBs system it does nothing.

> What is it used for?

You'll find some examples if you search online but it mostly appears to be some basic stuff, e.g., this is [from here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57125&start=100) (which is 3+ years old):

```
{
 "description" : "An XBMC media center distribution for Raspberry Pi",
 "flavour" : "RaspBMC",
 "imagefolder" : "/settings/os/RaspBMC",
 "keyboard" : "gb",
 "language" : "en",
 "partitions" : [
"/dev/mmcblk0p7",
"/dev/mmcblk0p8"
 ],
 "release_date" : "2013-08-20",
 "videomode" : 0
}
```

Some of this is likely for the NOOBS menu, and some of it maybe passed as options to the kernel or init -- in any case the general idea is pretty clear.  I would not bother investigating further as I doubt this system will suit your purposes well.

> I'm trying to customize an image and that sounds like something I should look at

This is ambiguous, but presuming you just want to automate installation, have a look around here for questions referencing *[puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software))* or *[chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software))* (if you search separately, you will find more things).  I notice [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51572/5538) references a chef spin-off/fork/plugin/module (?) specifically for the Pi.

Personally, I find it easiest to just script that kind of thing myself, although this is no doubt dependent on how well you understand the OS, etc.

Comment: Ah, thanks, exactly what I was after. `apply_noobs_os_config` does in fact delete itself after first run (so you need to look at source or the mounted image prior to first boot). It actually runs `raspi-config --apply-os-config`, which runs [this code](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/1cefeec830194bb5e38f826490bffed97a0f3f8c/raspi-config#L1367). Interestingly, most of the stuff people are putting in that file is ignored, only `flavour`, `language`, and `keyboard` are actually used (and even then, with some rules -- see source).

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a customized image, not just customize after boot. I'm also doing this from an automated build script -- it mounts the image, then uses [proot](https://github.com/proot-me/PRoot) (with qemu-arm) to execute customization inside. Running [pi-gen](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen) fully automated from my CI environment (without just giving the build root access) was crazy complicated, plus I am only trying to add a single application so compiling the whole was redundant.

Comment: And though this doesn't help me much, it was a quick fix for a minor annoyance I hadn't got to yet: the default `gb` keyboard layout doesn't allow me to type `|` from an `us` keyboard.

Comment: I had not noticed that about `raspi-config` (I've ignored the NOOBS stuff) -- it would not be that hard to generalize the whole thing that way (maybe someone should...), although I guess in that case you might as well write something new.  The `sed` line for parsing json is hacky (it's not really parsing json), but bash can source files with native associative arrays defined in them.